# How to build llvm tools with static libraries only

Tags: cmake, linker

I used **ldd** on llvm tools such **clang**, **clang**++, **llc** and find them all link with the same shared libraries, but I can't find codes that result in such dependency in CMakelists.txt.

**I want to build llvm tools with static libraries only, how can I do that?**

Shared library list:

- libachk.so
- libdl.so.2
- libtinfo.so.5
- libpthread.so.0
- libstdc++.so.6
- libm.so.6
- libgcc_s.so.1
- libc.so.6
- librt.so.1